# fedora grub rescue

Tags: linux, fedora, grub2, grub

I just installed Windows 8.1 on my system. After installing windows as always grub was replaced with windows bootloader. So I booted my fedora live USB and tried to restore the grub. The installation was sucessfull and it detected all my currently installed systems(Windows,Fedora24,Ubuntu16.04). 
After rebooting I was dropped into grub rescue.
So I typed the following.

```
insmod normal    
normal
```

After that I was given access to grub again but this time with all the OS in the list including the newly installed Windows8.1.
Is there any way to fix this,cause everything is working fine just at every boot I need to type the above commands.

**UPDATE** : I kind of screwed up I generated

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

the grub now loads fine but cannot detect Ubuntu.

Comment: Add those commands to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: check again @IporSircer

Comment: Add those lines manually after grub2-mkconfig finished its job.

Comment: Are you using efi boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was missing `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` ,so I generated with the help of `grub2-mkconfig`.

There was another problem `os-prober` was unable to detect the Ubuntu.
So I just mounted the Ubuntu file system and `os-prober` was able to detect Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

To update [GRUB 2](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2) configuration on UEFI systems you should specify the correct file:

EFI boot:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

On legacy boot :

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```